# If I leave the lights on all the time, am I burning more gas as a result?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

If I leave the lights on all the time, am I burning more gas as a result?

Does a fridge or AC unit have a specified gas drain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your generator is on it consumes gas at a constant rate (one per hour) regardless of what it's powering. There is no additional drain from appliances powered by it.